# Пытаюсь написать парсер страницы

Tags: android, html, java, auth, синтаксический-анализ

Учусь кодить на java+android платформе, уже перерыл кучу нета в поисках нормальных примеров. Насколько я понял сетевые задачи, а именно аля http get и post будут иметь тут место выполняются в async, итак...

Имеется сайт с простой html формой input с login и password.

- Нужно сперва получить страницу, найти саму форму т.е. get, сами поля login и password
- ввести нужные данные
- затем сделать post запрос с вставленными данными
- затем повторить get, чтобы получить страницу с уже выполненным входом, чтобы её распарсить, например jsoup'ом.

Подскажите есть ли какие-то готовые либы или ещё что-то для работы с формами, чтобы решить эту задачу, или пример кода как правильно это сделать, мучаюсь уже не первый день, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Зачем парсить страницу, если можно сразу отправить POST-запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема была в том что сайт работал с https, туго авторизовывался очень, я нашёл другой подход к его же базе, уже через http. 
и в итоге банально:

```
Response res = Jsoup
    .connect("http://хостецкий/")
    .data("login", "логин")
    .data("password", "пасс")
    .method(Method.POST)
    .timeout(60000)
    .execute();
```

сработал, уже разбираю результаты, теперь мучаю с регекс.